# MongoDB get value of document's Item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is my schema document in MongoDB:

```
{
"_id" : UUID("236073ce-a583-4df4-ba7d-bda6db186d10"),
"Lat" : "",
"Lng" : "",
"CreationDateTime" : ISODate("2017-09-26T06:39:29.105Z"),
"DeviceId" : "89984320001499681815",
"Topic" : "",
"UserId" : UUID("bca0db12-2246-49a5-8703-b03fee45e50f"),
"UserName" : "",
"Data" : {
    "AppVersion" : "",
    "AppName" : ""
},
"DeviceIdId" : ,
"FirstName" : " ",
"LastName" : "",
"AllowDomains" : "",
"JobLocationName" : ""
}
```

How could I get just DeviceId as a string?

I tried this :

```
var result;
db.getCollection('FinalLocation').find({}).forEach(function(u){
result = u.DeviceId;
});
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: In general, it must work. Do you get any error? Are you sure that your collection `FinalLocation` not empty?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak I got `Script executed successfully , but there are no result to show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code (if you want to display in robomongo)

```
        var result;
        db.getCollection('FinalLocation').find({}, {DeviceId: 1}).forEach(function(u){
        result = u.DeviceId;
        print(result);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this (if i understood your question correctly):

```
var result;
db.getCollection('FinalLocation').find({}, {DeviceId: 1}).forEach(function(u){
result = u.DeviceId;
});
```

It will work well)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: I am using robomongo .How could I print result into my screen?because I got `Script executed successfully , but there are no result to show`

Comment: Hmm, may be there are no data in the collection?
Are you sure that you have documents in a collection?